# tableMeta.rowData de customBodyRender en mui-datatable me retorna solo los datos del ultimo registro de la tabla

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datatables, material-ui

Estoy utilizando la librería [MuiDataTables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) para crear tablas en react. En una de sus funcionalidad me permite crear una columna personalizada donde creé un sub menú con varias opciones. Uno de los parámetros de la función trae los datos de la fila que se esta renderizando, el problema que al momento de hacer click en una de las opciones del submenu que creé, esta me devuelve solo los datos de la ultima fila, y no de la fila que se supone que estoy haciendo click.

```
customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
    //tableMeta.rowData trae los datos de la fila que se renderea
    return ()
}
```

E intentado dejar solo los iconos de las funciones sin el sub menú, y ahí funciona correctamente, el problema es que no quiero dejar una columna llena de iconos solo con tooltips, se vería muy feo, sobre todo en su versión Mobile.

Estoy pensando que quizás es un problema de lógica, pero no puedo pensar en cual seria la causa exacta

Cree un [replica del problema](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-mclaren-ivvlq?file=/src/App.js) para que sea mas fácil visualizar el problema

[image: Fila seleccionada]

[image: Datos mostrados]

Comment: Hola! Para poder recibir respuestas oportunas, es necesario que incluyas EN la pregunta, el código relevante. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.